# How do i test the execute part of a Batchclass

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

I have the following batch class for which i wrote a test but I think i still need to assert for the excecute part how would I achieve this. In the debug I do not have any errors my coverage is 58% and does not cover the execute part. The Actief__c in this case is a formula field.

Actief__c:

```
IF(AND(Startdatum__c <= TODAY(), Einddatum__c >= TODAY()), TRUE, 
IF(AND(Startdatum__c <= TODAY(), ISBLANK(Einddatum__c)), TRUE, 
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Startdatum__c), Einddatum__c >= TODAY()), TRUE, 
IF(AND(ISBLANK(Startdatum__c), ISBLANK(Einddatum__c)), TRUE, FALSE) 
) 
) 
)
```

Batchclass

```
global class UpdateActiveValue implements 
Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    // instance member to retain state across transactions
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT id, Name, Actief_hard__c, Actief__c FROM Relatie_Contact__c WHERE (Actief__c= true AND Actief_hard__c=false) OR (Actief__c= false AND Actief_hard__c=true)'
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Relatie_Contact__c> scope){
        // process each batch of records       
        for (Relatie_Contact__c Rc : scope) {

            Rc.Actief_hard__c  = Rc.Actief__c;

            // increment the instance member counter
            recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
        }
        update scope;
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed.');
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, 
                            JobItemsProcessed,
                            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                            FROM AsyncApexJob
                            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        // call some utility   
    }    
}
```

Testclass

```
@isTest
private class UpdateActiveValueTest {

    @testSetup 
    static void setup() {

        //Integer numAccts;
        Integer numContactsPerAcct;

        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++) {
            Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i);
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;

        List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer j=0;j<200;j++) {
            Account acct = accts[j];            
            // For each account just inserted, add contacts
            cons.add(new Contact(firstname='Test'+j,
                                 lastname='Test'+j,
                                 AccountId=acct.Id)); 
        }
        // Insert all contacts for all accounts
        insert cons;

        List<Relatie_Contact__c> Rc = new List<Relatie_Contact__c>();
        // insert 200 Leads
        for (Integer i=0;i<200;i++) {
            Rc.add(new Relatie_Contact__c(Contactpersoon__c = cons[i].id, 
                                          Relatiesoort__c ='Vereniging: Medewerker',Relatietype__c='Tennisleraar', 
                                          Organisatie__c  =cons[i].accountId, Startdatum__c=System.today()));
        }
        insert Rc;       
    }

    static testmethod void test() {        
        Test.startTest();
        UpdateActiveValue insertRc = new UpdateActiveValue();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(insertRc);
        Test.stopTest();

        // after the testing stops, assert records were updated properly
        System.assertEquals(200, [select count() from Relatie_Contact__c where Actief_hard__c = true]);

    }
}
```

Tried the following whit no errors in the debug still no coverage for the execute part

```
@isTest
private class UpdateActiveValueTest {

    @testSetup 
    static void setup() {

        //Integer numAccts;
        Integer numContactsPerAcct;

        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<200;i++) {
            Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i);
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;

        List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
        for (Integer j=0;j<200;j++) {
            Account acct = accts[j];            
            // For each account just inserted, add contacts
            cons.add(new Contact(firstname='Test'+j,
                                 lastname='Test'+j,
                                 AccountId=acct.Id)); 
        }
        // Insert all contacts for all accounts
        insert cons;
    }

    static testMethod void testActiveBatch()
    {
        List<Relatie_Contact__c> records = new List<Relatie_Contact__c>();
        for (Contact parent : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact])
        {
            records.add(new Relatie_Contact__c(Contactpersoon__c = parent.id, 
                                               Relatiesoort__c ='Vereniging: Medewerker',Relatietype__c='Tennisleraar', 
                                               Organisatie__c  =parent.accountId, Startdatum__c=System.Today(), Einddatum__c=null,
                                               Actief_hard__c = false));
        }
        Insert records;
        Test.startTest();     
        Database.executeBatch(new UpdateActiveValue());
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(200, [select count() from Relatie_Contact__c where Actief_hard__c = true]);
        // System.assertEquals(true, [select Actief_hard__c from Relatie_Contact__c LIMIT 1].Actief_hard__c);

    }

    static testMethod void testInactiveBatch()
    {
        List<Relatie_Contact__c> records = new List<Relatie_Contact__c>();
        for (Contact parent : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact])
        {
            records.add(new Relatie_Contact__c(Contactpersoon__c = parent.id, 
                                               Relatiesoort__c ='Vereniging: Medewerker',Relatietype__c='Tennisleraar', 
                                               Organisatie__c  =parent.accountId, Startdatum__c=System.Today(), Einddatum__c=null,
                                               Actief_hard__c = true));
        }
        Insert records;
        Test.startTest();     
        Database.executeBatch(new UpdateActiveValue());
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(200, [select count() from Relatie_Contact__c where Actief_hard__c = true]);
    }    

}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing while not covering the execute method? Have you debugged in the batch class what start method returns

Comment: @RCS In the debug I do not have any errors my coverage is 58% and does not cover the execute part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your query locator to return records. Look at your filter:

```
WHERE (Actief__c= true AND Actief_hard__c=false) OR (Actief__c= false AND Actief_hard__c=true)
```

When you set up your records, you don't specify a value for either field. You shouldn't really create these records in your `@TestSetup`, but rather have one unit test for each condition set above.

```
static testMethod void testActiveBatch()
{
    List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject>();
    for (Contact parent : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact])
    {
        records.add(new MyObject__c(
            Checkbox1__c=true, Checkbox2__c=false //, other fields
        ));

        Test.startTest();
            Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());
        Test.stopTest();

        // assert on results
    }
}
static testMethod void testInactiveBatch()
{
    List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject>();
    for (Contact parent : [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact])
    {
        records.add(new MyObject__c(
            Checkbox1__c=false, Checkbox2__c=true //, other fields
        ));

        Test.startTest();
            Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());
        Test.stopTest();

        // assert on results
    }
}
```

Comment: Actief__c field is a formula field how can I set a value for this in my testclass?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the formula.

Comment: Just did added the formula field

Comment: Your formula is needlessly complex, but you can set it to true by specifying both date fields as null. Set it to false by specifying both date fields as today.

Comment: I followed your advice but still no solution. I added my test above. I tried with both date fields null and both System.today(). My first assertion gives me 200 records true but the execute part is not tested. What am I missing here?